# how to filter array with includes an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, include

here is my first array

```
let specificCoin = ["Ethereum","Bitcoin"]
```

and here is the second one

```
 let coins =[
    {
        name: 'Bitcoin',
    },
    {
        name: 'Ethereum',
    },
    {
        name: 'Solana',
    },
    {
        name: 'BinanceCoin',
    }]
```

i wondering how can i filter the coins array with includes in specificCoin array
something like that:

```
coins.filter(a => { return a.name.includes(specificCoin) })
```

result: `[{name: 'Ethereum',},{name: 'Bitcoin'}]`

and i also would like to know if there are two same objects value how can i get both in it,
using this code

```
let dataAssest = data.map(b => b.assestSymbol.toLowerCase())
    let filtered = coins.filter(coin => dataAssest.includes(coin.symbol))
```

image of result:
[Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdtbd.png)

but that ain’t work, i hope you guys can give a good solution :)

Comment: You need to check if `specificCoin` includes `a.name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way around

```js
let specificCoin = ['ETH', 'BTC'].map(symbol => symbol.toLowerCase())

let coins = [{ id: 'Bitcoin', symbol: 'btc' }, { id: 'Ethereum', symbol: 'eth' }, { id: 'Solana', symbol: 'sol'}, { id: 'BinanceCoin', symbol: 'bnb'  }];

const filtered = coins.filter(coin => specificCoin.includes(coin.symbol.toLowerCase()))

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: what about if i have same object value in array, how can i includes both ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: `let coins =[{name: 'Bitcoin'},{name: 'Ethereum',},{name:'Ethereum',}]` with that array your code return to me `[{name: 'Bitcoin',},{name: 'Ethereum'}]`, how can i get both "Ethereum" after filter. like this result: `[{name: 'Bitcoin',},{name: 'Ethereum'}, {name: 'Ethereum'}]`

Comment: Try my code with both - it works

Comment: i tried that ain’t work it’s not return to me twice if there are same objects, i think that need to to if it's already includes: include again but i have no idea how to make it correct

Comment: What is expected output? I’ll look later

Comment: I added a picture and code that i tried to my question here you can see it above, thanks you sir

Comment: I do not understand why you have btc twice in the first array. My code will work on testing the symbol in the second array against the first array. Can you show the actual input array and the expected output array? You code does not match the image

Comment: the first array that you see on image it is the first line of code and the second one it is the second line of code...